# Function returns NoneType after getting it wrong the first time

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion, nonetype

I have a function that asks for some specific data. I have another function that takes input, and if it is what it should be, it assigns to the variable from it was called.

The problem is that if I get a wrong value, then it will always return `NoneType` object, even if I get the good answer the second time.

I tried removing the `clear()`. I tried to add more return, even where the answer should not pass through. I tried adding a second argument to function with the name of the variable I am trying to assign a value

```
def ask_input_string(text):

    ''' Takes only one argument. This function asks for input when it is called and returns the value but with the argument provided as text. '''

    variable=input(text)
    if variable=="":
        print("\nField must not be empty")  
        ask_input_string(text)
    try:
        int(variable)
        print("\nPlease enter a name!")
        ask_input_string(text)

    except ValueError:
        return variable

def menu_add():
    clear()

    print("\nPlease add the data required!\n")

    nume=ask_input_string("Name of animal: ")

    animal_type=ask_input_string("\nAnimal Type: ")
```

Expected Result:

If I add a wrong value, It asks for the correct one. I give the correct one, and it assigns to the variable it was called from.

Actual Result:

If I give the wrong answer at least 1 time, then even if I get the correct one, it will always assign `NoneType` to the variable it was called from.

If I give the correct answer the first time, it works. It does not work if I give a wrong answer in first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def ask_input_string(text):
    variable = input(text)
    if variable == "":
        print("\nField must not be empty")
        return ask_input_string(text)

    try:
        int(variable)
        print("\nPlease enter a name!")
        return ask_input_string(text)
    except ValueError:
        return variable
```

You have to return the values from the recursive call. You wouldn't throw away the result of a function like this normally, and recursion isn't really special, it's just another function call.

Comment: The input is supposed to only be string, but not an integer. So basicaly that is a name, i can't be an empty field or some numbers

Comment: @Seeven sorry, I'm so used to people wanting to convert input to an integer I didn't pay close enough attention.

Comment: It tries to convert to integer. If it fails (because it is a string) then returns the value. The priblem is, if in the first place i inter an integer, and second time i enter a string, it will return a noneType, but if i give in the first place a string it returns a string.

Comment: @Seeven I understand that, so I reverted the exception handling part. Just put in the returns and you're good to go. But your terminology is a bit off - `variable` is always a string, it just might be a string that happens to be interpretable as a number.

Comment: hmm... it works.... but i don't really comprehend why...thanks by the way

Comment: @Seeven try running your program through the Thonny debugger and see if that helps you understand.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio code. I used the debuger to check every step, and what i seen is that it lost the track of variable, now it keeps the value intact. I think i understood. Can i give an upvote or someting similar?